# Structuring HTML so text displays in one paragraph

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I'm working on a VBA code in Excel to get input from reports and send emails.

I'm trying to avoid line breaks in my email body.

```vba
With olMail
    .To = rep
    .Subject = title & " - " & EndTitle
    '.Recipients.Add rep
    .Attachments.Add filePath & "\" & title & " - " & EndTitle & ".pdf"
    .htmlBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Arial><b><u>Here is an email</u></b></BODY>" & "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Arial><b><u>Here is an email</u></b></BODY>" _
                & "<br>" & "<b>HK</b>" & "<b>" & amt & "</b>" _
                & "<br>" & "Value date" & "<b>" & Trans & "</b>" & "<br>" & 
     initial
    .Display 

    '.Send
End With
```

My email looked like this

> Here is the email
>     Here is the email

What I want the email body to look like

> Here is the email Here is the email

(on the same line)

Comment: Also, dont use more than one `<body>` tag, as that is not valid HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to apply <body> tag to the rest of other line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
.htmlBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Arial><b><u>Here is an emailHere is an email</u></b>" _
            & "<br>" & "<b>HK" & amt & "</b>" _
            & "<br>" & "Value date" & "<b>" & Trans & "</b>" & "<br>" & initial & "</BODY>"
```

Or this, depending on which line breaks you want gone:

```
.htmlBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Arial><b><u>Here is an emailHere is an email</u></b>" _
            & "<b>HK" & amt & "</b>" _
            & "Value date" & "<b>" & Trans & "</b>" & initial & "</BODY>"
```

See how I encapsulated all the HTML between the opening and closing BODY tags?